# JavaScript split on multiple delimiters and preserve quoted text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string...

```
'(!false >=stuff 300 OR 200 "TEST DATA")'
```

I figure out how to preserve quoted text using the following...

```
test.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)
```

However, the output is not what I want...

```
[ 'false', 'stuff', '300', 'OR', '200', '"TEST DATA"' ]
```

There is a list of symbols I need to preserve...

```
{'<', '>', '<=', '=>', '=', '!'}
```

so that my split should look as follows...

```
['(', '!', 'false', '>=', 'stuff', '300', 'OR', '200', '"TEST DATA"', ')']
```

How can I add onto my `match` function to preserve the following? I'm not very good with `regex`.

Comment: Your result seems incomplete. It's missing the last `)` and a closing `]`.

Comment: @FrankerZ Ah thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```js
let str = '(!false >=stuff 300 OR 200 "TEST DATA")'

let arr = str.match(/"[^"]*"|[<>]=|[^\w\s]|\w+/g)

console.log(arr)
//=> ["(", "!", "false", ">=", "stuff", "300", "OR", "200", ""TEST DATA"", ")"]
```

Regex has following alternatives:

- `"[^"]*"`: Match a quoted string
- `[<>]=`: Match `<=` or `>=`
- `[^\w\s]`: Match any non-space, non-word character
- `\w+`: Match any word